# leaflet cache layer

Tags: javascript, frontend, leafletjs

Есть карта Leaflet и tileLayer, необходимо принудительно перезагрузить определенную координатную область по всем зумам, грубо говоря тайл изменился или область, и надо сказать лефлету что бы он перезагрузил тайлы для всех зумов заново (обновил кеш). судя по документации http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#tilelayer-bindpopup есть функция redraw(), но она перезагружает только видимый в текущий момент зум. Есть какие идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: Добавить параметр к url в настройкам, чтобы были другие адреса?

Comment: добавлю я url а дальше то что с ним делать, вопрос не в том что поменялся адрес с которого надо стащить тайл, а поменялась информация на этом тайле по прежнему адресу, а лефлет ни сном ни духом что надо его обновить, и по этому продолжает отображать по страрому.